# What is University Declaration of the Current Year strictly?

Tags: business-language

I am reading [this](http://openlab.web.cern.ch/summer-student-programme) website where it says

> The application must be submitted - - with the following documents attached to it: - - the university declaration for the current year.

I think the University Declaration of the Current year is the *Certificate of the Student Status* that the student is studying in the university that time. 
I can also get a document Called *Transcript of Records* which has the same pieces of information as the former document but also much more (all courses completed also). This document would be a big list and I do not want to annoy the reader by too much information.

I can also cut the latter document to contain only the first page which has all the info of the former document but also courses completed recently during the recent study year.

**What should you include in University Declaration of the Current Year?** 
I think maximally the Certificate of student status + recent courses completed from the current (study) year.

Comment: Your use of CaPiTalS makes it look like something it probably isn't. Changing _for_ to _of_ is also confusing. What they want is a document that refers to the current year (so not an old one). That document is a declaration from a university. What has to be in the declaration is a completely different matter, and we cannot answer that based on language.

Comment: So could you share what is that document about?

Comment: I asked them and they want the Certificate of Student status only. They will change the language later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a Google search for the term "the university declaration **for** the current year" (note that it is *for*, not *of* — you seem to have been incorrectly using those prepositions interchangeably) indicates that it is a CERN-only usage.

For this reason, it seems appropriate to contact CERN for clarification as soon as possible in order to find out what exactly they mean by this idiosyncratic usage. That seems like a much more sensible approach than guessing or making assumptions — especially since the application deadline of 28 February is only a few days away, and therefore there won't be time to rectify any misunderstandings before the deadline has passed.